# Get the id of all elements that have a certain class and then run a function with that id

Tags: jquery, primary-key

I have several buttons:

```
<button id="pill_a" class="btn-pill cyan">hola</button>
<button id="pill_b" class="btn-pill">adios</button>
<button id="pill_c" class="btn-pill cyan">sup</button>
```

I want to run a function only with the ones that have the class "cyan". The function needs the id of the buttons

I tried to use an `if` condition when it runs the page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   
  if($('.btn-pill').hasClass("cyan")){
     var id = $("button.cyan).attr('id');
     addRow(id);
  }
});
```

but it appears its only being able to do it once (with the first button) but not the other ones. Why? Do I need to create a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to access attr of multiples elements(here using class selector) it will give the first element's attribute only. You need to loop the elements to get the desired functionality

`$('.btn-pill.cyan').each(function(){  addRow($(this).attr('id')) })`

Comment: ah thanks!! I had a feeling it was with the .each loop but i didn't know exactly how to implement it! thanks a lot!